# create folds with variable indicating an observation in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I'm using R to analyse some data and I need to create folds to cross-validate. One observation is made up by several rows so I cannot just simply use (for example) the CreateFolds function. I have a variable that indicates which row belongs to which subject, so I think I need to use this to create the folds.

How can I do this?

example:

```
indicator    var1    var2    var3    y
1            2       2       3       10
1            2       3       3       10
2            2       1       1       4
2            1       2       2       4
```

The indicator indicates that it is from the same subject.

Comment: The `indicator` variable is the number of each testing fold of your cross-validation?

Comment: No, the indicator variable indicates from which subject the observation is. So the 1 indicates it came from subject 1 and those rows belong together and should not be separated during the making of the folds

Comment: And you have the same number of observations for each subject?

Comment: No this differs for some subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `data.frame` and you want to do a K-cross-validation, you can do

```
library(dplyr)    
mutate(df, fold = sample(rep_len(1:K, n_distinct(indicator)))[indicator])
```

Comment: Thank you! And what if I want to make a 80%-20% split for a training and test set?

Comment: Just take K = 5, and choose which fold is your test set.

Comment: It works when I create a train and test set, but when I want to use it to do 10 fold cross-validation on the training set it returns NA for 1/6 of the data. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: If you want 10-fold, you use K = 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it! If you do the following it does not separate the rows that are indicated by the indicator

```
# get the levels of the indicator
d$indicator <- as.factor(d$indicator)
indicatorlevels <- levels(d$indicator)

# create folds with these levels
library(caTools)
set.seed(1)
folds <- sample.split(indicatorlevels, SplitRatio = 0.8)

# select test ans training vacancies
training.indicator <- subset(indicatorlevels, folds == TRUE)
test.indicator <- subset(indicatorlevels, folds == FALSE)

# create test and training dataset
train <- d[d$indicator %in% training.indicator,]
test <- d[d$indicator %in% test.indicator,]
```

Does someone know a more elegant way of doing this?